# start whatsapp with android.content.Intent.ACTION_SENDTO

Tags: android, android-intent, uri, messaging, whatsapp

I'm triying to start whatsapp with an android intent:

```
String uri = "smsto:+123456";
Intent messageIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO, Uri.parse(uri));
messageIntent.putExtra("sms_body", "My Message");
startActivity(messageIntent);
```

It works great if the user picks the normal messaging application. But not if the user selects whatsapp from the chooser. The "compose text field" from whatsapp remains empty.

What am I doing wrong here? Do I need another `putExtra()`?

Comment: Have you asked the developers behind whatsapp?

Comment: no. let me do that. I will report back.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Here is the answer from the whatsapp android support team:

[image]

Comment: LOL that's funny