# Android : Send WhatsApp Image with Caption programmatically in background without opening WhatsApp application : Using Accessibility

Tags: android, whatsapp, accessibilityservice

I created an Android Application.

and I want to send an image on Whatsapp, In Background. I came to know it can only be done by Accessibility API's.

I was able to send the Text ( Thanx to : https://stackoverflow.com/a/71804457/5323184 ) ,
but for image. I am unable to

I followed a similar approach for images : But its not sending it automatically.

```
 AccessibilityServiceManager serviceManager = new AccessibilityServiceManager(activity.mContext);
            if (serviceManager.hasAccessibilityServicePermission(WhatsAppAccessibilityServices.class)) {
                File appFolderLocation = new File(cachePath, OUTPUT_RENT_RECEIPT_PNG_NAME);
                Uri contentUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(activity.mContext, BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID.concat(".provider"), appFolderLocation);

                if (contentUri == null) {
                    In_Place.toastHelper.toastErrorMsg("File Not Present");
                } else {
                    String toNumber = getFormattedNumber(activity.getTenantContactNumber());
                    toNumber = toNumber.replace("+", "").replace(" ", ""); // E164 format without '+' sign

                    Intent sendIntent = new Intent("android.intent.action.MAIN");
                    sendIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                    sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, caption);
                    sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, contentUri);
                    sendIntent.setDataAndType(contentUri, activity.mContext.getContentResolver().getType(contentUri));
                    sendIntent.putExtra("jid", toNumber + "@s.whatsapp.net"); //phone number without "+" prefix
                    sendIntent.setPackage(packageName); //com.whatsapp //com.whatsapp.w4b
                    sendIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                    sendIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
                    activity.mContext.startActivity(sendIntent);
                }
            } else {
                serviceManager.requestUserForAccessibilityService((Activity) activity.mContext);
            }
```

Comment: I am using this code : https://stackoverflow.com/a/71804457/5323184

Comment: You cannot use an accessibility service to send a message without even opening whatsapp and do it in background. It can only be done in the app by opening whatsapp.